# Reading a file from server using Java

Tags: java, android

There is file PULS.TXT on URl mobile.puls-radio.ru
How can I read this file from java code ?
I use this code, but does not work

```
URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://mobile.puls-radio.ru/PULS.txt");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        Log.i("TEST", s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: http://mobile.puls-radio.ru/PULS.txt doesn't seem to exist

Comment: What do you mean with doesn't work? An exception is thrown? or it doesn't log anything? Also, what's the content of txt file? Post a sample, please

Comment: all is good. I was wrong with name file